# How can I report off generic sql data in Key/Value pairs?

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, reporting, adhoc, cognos

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.

I have some normalized tables, laid out (simplified) as follows:

```
Person
(
     PersonId
     Email
)

Info
(
     InfoId
     InfoDescr
)

PersonInfo
(
     PersonId
     InfoId
     InfoValue
)
```

I need to provide users some ad hoc reporting to this. My boss wants me to use Cognos, and we have Crystal Reports and Sql Server Report Services available to us as well.

How can I allow a user to query the data as follows:

```
Give me all people in zipcode x who are subscribed to our newsletter
     (Assuming Zipcode and Newsletter are stored as Info records)
```

I've written a view that flattens the data like so

```
 PersonId, Email,    InfoId, InfoDescr,  InfoValue
 1         me@me.com 2       Zipcode     12345
```

I want the user to be able to pick whatever Infos they want, and give criteria to filter them down.

Any recommendations would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Crystal Reports. Build a simple form with comboboxes/filters that would facilitate the UI. Through the form, the user will pick and filter the wanted criteria. Use this criteria to create the SQL query and use the resulting table as a the datasource for the Crystal report. If you're new to crystal and need some sample code, just comment...

Comment: I'm not new to Crystal, we have XI 12.5. I guess I'm still not sure how they would add filters dynamically to get the data they want.

Comment: Not sure I understood your question but I'll try to answer. How about filling a combobox with all the InfoDescr data so that the user can select the desired info and then a textbox to insert the criteria for the filter. You can then repeat this process as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with Excel. Please see [this accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20275/solutions-for-reporting-off-of-an-eav-structured-database) for details.

In short, I used a dynamic pivot table in a stored procedure. The stored procedure called a View that I created which denormalizes the data. I think used MS Query to hook the stored procedure up to Excel 2010. This loads it up into a nicely formatted table that allows the end user to sort and filter to their heart's content.